# Does quicksort with randomized median-of-three do appreciably better than randomized quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort

I was just answering a question about different approaches for picking the partition in a quicksort implementation and came up with a question that I honestly don't know how to answer.  It's a bit math-heavy, and this may be the wrong site on which to ask this, so if this needs to move please let me know and I'll gladly migrate it elsewhere.

It's well-known that a quicksort implementation that picks its pivots uniformly at random will end up running in expected O(n lg n) time (there's a nice proof of this [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Randomized_quicksort_expected_complexity)).  However, due to the cost of generating random numbers, many quicksort implementations don't pick pivots randomly, but instead rely on a "median-of-three" approach in which three elements are chosen deterministically and of which the median is chosen as the pivot.  This is known to degenerate to O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case (see [this great paper](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf) on how to generate those worst-case inputs, for example).

Now, suppose that we **combine** these two approaches by picking three random elements from the sequence and using their median as the choice of pivot.  I know that this also guarantees O(n lg n) average-case runtime using a slightly different proof than the one for the regular randomized quicksort.  However, I have no idea what the constant factor in front of the n lg n term is in this particular quicksort implementation.  For regular randomized quicksort Wikipedia lists the actual runtime of randomized quicksort as requiring at most 1.39 n lg n comparisons (using lg as the binary logarithm).

My question is this: **does anyone know of a way to derive the constant factor for the number of comparisons made using a "median-of-three" randomized quicksort**?  If we go even more generally, is there an expression for the constant factor on quicksort using a randomized median-of-k approach?  I'm curious because I think it would be fascinating to see if there is some "sweet spot" of this approach that makes fewer comparisons than other randomized quicksort implementations.  I mean, wouldn't it be cool to be able to say that randomized quicksort with a randomized median-of-six pivot choice makes the fewest comparisons?  Or be able to conclusively say that you should just pick a pivot element at random?

Comment: It may be math-heavy but it falls under clause 2 of the FAQ (a software algorithm) so I'd say it belongs here. You should keep in mind that efficiency depends on both the algorithm _and_ data. Even bubble sort is insanely efficient if the list is mostly sorted already (in fact, it even outperforms some others). Having said that, my answer is "stuffed if I know" but +1 for an interesting question :-)

Comment: Wouldn't generating 3 random numbers be *more* costly than generating 1 random number?

Comment: Yes, but with very high probability (e.g., 1 - 1/n^2), we need a total of only O(n) random numbers. Asymptotically, this does not represent a significant added cost.

Comment: Quick sort is 1.39 n log n (as wiki said), if this algorithm works better it's at least  n log n, and this isn't important, and I think this isn't a good math problem, this improvements are useless, for example if you improve approximation factor just by epsilon is good idea (because it will multiply by big numbers), but improving 1.39nlogn to nlog n?! main problem is more important than this improvements. but good luck with this, you can ask it in Math.StackExchange or cstheory....

Comment: +1 for a good question, and if i could, +0.5 extra for the link to generating worst-case-inducing inputs.

Comment: Do you really need a *strong* random number generator? Surely, you only need something independent of the distribution of the data (with a reasonably high probability). One of those multiply-by-big-prime-modulo-2^n things would probably be fine, as often used for hash tables.

Comment: The best way to test the relative performance of two algorithms with the same asymptotic performance is literally to run them many times with varied reasonably-sized data and analyse the times. After all, when it comes to constant factors, there's plenty of relevant issues other than the numbers of comparisons and swaps, such as hardware issues (cache etc). In this case the two algorithms almost identical anyway, but the thing about surprises is you don't anticipate them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  So what would you suggest? the qsort implementation of the standard library already has better performance than the median of 3... as pivot choice.

Comment: @templatetypedef So what are your conclusions ?randomized quicksort with a randomized median-of-six pivot choice makes the fewest comparisons? pick a pivot element at random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant for the usual randomized quicksort is easy to compute because the probability that two elements k locations apart are compared is exactly 2/(k+1): the probability that one of the those two elements is chosen as a pivot before any of the k-1 elements between them. Unfortunately nothing so clever applies to your algorithm.

I'm hesitant to attempt your bolded question because I *can* answer your "underlying" question: asymptotically speaking, there is no "sweet spot". The total added cost of computing medians of k elements, even O(n<sup>1 - ε</sup>) elements, is linear, and the constant for the n log n term decreases with the array being split more evenly. The catch is of course constants on the linear term that are spectacularly impractical, highlighting one of the drawbacks of asymptotic analysis.

---

Based on my comments below, I guess k = O(n<sup>α</sup>) for 0 < α < 1 is the "sweet spot".

Comment: Why "even O(n<sup>1 - ε</sup>) elements" rather than the stronger and equally true "even all n elements"?

Comment: I'm summing over all recursive calls. All n would lead to a (n log n)-sized cost.

Comment: Even n^ε should be enough to get the best n log n constant anyway.

Comment: Even polylog might work, but I can't do the details in my head.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a heuristic derivation of the constant. I think it can be made rigorous, with a lot more effort.

Let P be a continuous random variable with values in [0, 1]. Intuitively, P is the fraction of values less than the pivot. We're looking to find the constant c such that

c n lg n = **E**[n + c P n lg (P n) + c (1 - P) n lg ((1 - P) n)].

A little bit of algebra later, we have

c = 1/**E**[-P lg P - (1 - P) lg (1 - P))].

In other words, c is the reciprocal of the expected entropy of the Bernoulli distribution with mean P. Intuitively, for each element, we need to compare it to pivots in a way that yields about lg n bits of information.

When P is uniform, the pdf of P is 1. The constant is

```
In[1]:= -1/NIntegrate[x Log[2, x] + (1 - x) Log[2, 1 - x], {x, 0, 1}]

Out[1]= 1.38629
```

When the pivot is a median of 3, the pdf of P is 6 x (1 - x). The constant is

```
In[2]:= -1/NIntegrate[6 x (1 - x) (x Log[2, x] + (1 - x) Log[2, 1 - x]), {x, 0, 1}]

Out[2]= 1.18825
```

Comment: For a median of 2 k + 1 elements, the pdf is (2 k + 1)!/(k!)^2 * x^k (1 - x)^k. Go nuts.

Comment: @userOVER9000- This looks great, but your logic doesn't account for the extra comparisons made in order to do the median of k, nor does it handle the fact that we're working in discrete rather than continuous domains.  Is there a way to address this?

Comment: Extra comparisons: these are at most linear by the Master Theorem, as pointed out by _a dabbler_. Discrete rather than continuous: we can couple P with the actual distribution of the median index with error O(1/n) and leave out the pivot from the recursion with another O(1/n) error. After a bunch of tedious analysis, the total error should be linear.

Answer (score 4):

If the initial state of the set is randomly ordered, you will get the exact same constant factor for randomly picking three items to calculate the median as when picking three items deterministically.

The motive for picking item by random would be that the deterministic method would give a result that is worse than the average. If the deterministic method gives a good median, you can't improve on it by picking items by random.

So, which ever method gives the best result depends on the input data, it can't be determined for every possible set.

The only sure way to lower the constant factor is to increase the number of items that you use to calcuate the median, but at some point calculating the median will be more expensive than what you gain by getting a better median value.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't imrpove the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.  Bentley and McIlroy, authors of the [`C` standard library's `qsort` function](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c), wrote in their paper, [Engineering a Sort Function](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf) the following numbers:

- 1.386 n lg n average comparisons using first, middle or a randomized pivot
- 1.188 n lg n average comparisons using a median of 3 pivot
- 1.094 n lg n average comparisons using a median of 3 medians pivot

According to the above paper:

> Our final code therefore chooses the middle element of smaller arrays,
>   the median of the first, middle and last elements of a mid-sized
>   array, and the pseudo-median of nine evenly spaced elements of a large
>   array.

Comment: This would seemingly be a pseudo random approach to try and achieve the 3 random element median pivot as stated in the first post.  is using random numbers really that heavy for use of pivots ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: If you use the *median-of-three* approach, and you find it to be better, why not use a *median-of-five* or *median-of-eleven* approach? And while you are on it, maybe one can think of a *median-of-n* optimization... hmmm... Ok, that is obviously a bad idea (since you would have to sort your sequence for that...).

Basically, to choose your pivot element as the *median-of-m* elements, you sort those *m* elements, right? Therefore, I'd simply guess, that one of the constants you are looking for is "2": By first sorting 3 elements to choose your pivot you execute how many additional comparisons? Lets say its 2. You do this inside the quicksort over and over again. A basic conclusion would be that the *median-of-3* is therefore 2-times slower then the simple random quicksort.

But what is working for you here? That you get a better device-and-conquer-distribution, and you are better protected against the degenerated case (a bit).

So, back to my infamous question at the beginning: Why not choose the pivot element from a *median-of-m*, m being 5, 7, n/3, or so. There must be a *sweet spot* where the sorting of the *m* elements is worse then the gain from the better divide-and-conquer behavior and quicksort. I guess, this sweet-spot is there very early -- you have to fight first against the constant factor of *2* comparisons if you choose *median-of-3*. It is worth an experiment, I admit, but I would not be too expectant of the result :-) But if I am wrong, and the gain is huge: don't stop at 3!

Comment: The bottom of this page suggests using median-of-sqrt(N/log(N)).  How he got that, I honestly don't understand.  http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/sorting/sorting.html

Comment: interesting. This guy did his math which I was just guessing. Actually, the "70" rings a bell, I think I've heard this *sweet spot* number before.